# Best practise AddHandler & RemoveHandler or Public boolean variable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213243/sub-with-selectedindexchanged-handle-calls-itself) a few months ago. Where I had a subroutine with a selectedindexchanged handler calling itself as it was changing the selected index of the control.

I was told of two ways to solve this problem, a public boolean, or adding and removing the event handlers during runtime. I am starting to find more cases of this type of problem. What is best practise to solve them?

A public boolean seems like a simple but cluttered fix to be as I would eventually end up with several public booleans relating to whether different subroutines should run. Adding and removing handlers seems cleaner, but it feels like i am asking the compiler to do a lot of work.

Comment: A note on terminology: saying “a public boolean” is like saying “a cellulose-wrapped sugar store” instead of “apple”. What you are talking about is called a “flag” but “on/off switch” or even “boolean variable” would be OK choices of word.

Comment: If you are looking to improve you code then look for a pattern where you are not changing the index in the event handler.   And you really think you are tiring out the compiler?

Comment: Don't change the index if you don't need to. Don't put the same value as the one currently in it. That way you don't need any special code to handle this case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: And yet `public boolean variable` is very specific, whereas a flag can mean more than that. Also a flag does not specify scope. `public flag` sounds more like a flag you have near embassies or schools. On-off switch is the one you use to turn on the lights. To sum up, I am perfectly okay with `public boolean`, `public integer` etc., especially in VB.NET world.

Comment: @Neolisk It’s specific in all the wrong things, like my fruit example. Scope – completely unimportant here. It shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how the parts fit together. It’s an example of [cargo-cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo-cult_programming).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I believe that being specific is very important for questions. Using a `Public Boolean` as a flag is one of the solutions I had to this problem. Using `Static Boolean` see @bdasnett's answer, was beyond my knowledge. A static Boolean and a public Boolean are both types of flag, therefore I might not have got this answer if I used `flag` in the question. I wouldn't say I am showing a fundamental misunderstanding, but a lack of knowledge, which is surely why I am here asking the question.

Comment: @Pezzzz I’m not disputing the importance of being specific. But: (1) it’s a title. Titles need to be concise, and not necessarily completely specific; and (2) there’s still such a thing as being specific in the *wrong* things. `Public` is irrelevant information here. What’s more, `Public` and `Static` are orthogonal concepts. Re the lack of knowledge: hence my comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a static boolean within the event handler.  Here is a short example using the TextBox.TextChanged event handler.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, _
                                 e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Debug.WriteLine("1")
    Static reentrant As Boolean = False
    If Not reentrant Then
        Debug.WriteLine("2")
        reentrant = True
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper
        reentrant = False
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("3")
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine("4")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to only change the text if it needs to be changed (The event is only raised when the text property is assigned).
This would produce 2 runs of the routine just like the others but no additional occurances same as the boolean.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, _
                             e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    if not TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper
    End If
End Sub
```